# Java Priorotyqueue representation in PHP

Tags: java, php, collections, priority-queue

I need to port certain features of the Java PriorityQueue to PHP, but I'm inexperienced in Java. For my first try, I just sorted the list based on priority and it works to some degree. The problem comes when items with the same priority is inserted. I always put them AFTER all the same priority elements, but that didn't give equal results with java.

Then I tried to do it with strings, compared by length, both in Java, and my PHP alternative. The 10 strings were in order:

```
"eeny","meeny","miny","moe","catch","the","tiger","by","his","toe"
```

My PHP class ordered them by length, and put same length strings **after** ones already there: `by,moe,the,his,toe,eeny,miny,meeny,catch,tiger`

However, Java gave some "hectic" order:
`by,moe,the,his,toe,miny,tiger,meeny,eeny,catch`

So 4 char length strings placed *after* 5 char strings.

After I analyzed this, I think I found out how it works, but I'm not sure. I think when a new item has a priority that'd place it somewhere inside the queue, it will replace the item already there, and that item goes to the end of the queue, regardless it's priority. Am I right? If yes, that does not sound too logical for me...

Here's my Java test code:

```
PriorityQueue<String> queue = new PriorityQueue<String>(1,new Comparator<String>(){
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            return s1.length() - s2.length();
        }
});        

    queue.offer("eeny");
    queue.offer("meeny");
    queue.offer("miny");
    queue.offer("moe");
    queue.offer("Catch");
    queue.offer("the");
    queue.offer("tiger");
    queue.offer("By");
    queue.offer("his");
    queue.offer("toe");

    for(int i=1;i<=10;i++) {
       System.out.println(queue.remove());
    }
```

Since there are four 3 char length strings, they are together, but in the order of **"moe","his","toe","the"** which is neither the FIFO order nor alphabetical. Why is that?

Comment: May this helps: http://php.net/manual/en/class.splpriorityqueue.php

Comment: And is this `meeny,eeny` explaind by java? Dont getting the sorting behavior here?

Comment: I compared the strings by their length, not alphabetically, so eeny which is 4 chars should come before meeny, which is 5

Comment: And that the way you set the priority here?

Comment: I thing you should try SPL PriorityQueue.

Comment: I tried to use .remove() in Java instead of iterating through the queue, and now the same priority items are together, but still not in the order of insertion. Shouldn't a queue be FIFO?

Comment: Im not a java coder, sry. Dont know how it works in java.

Comment: Ok, I just don't get it. Java is not going to be my favorite language.
Elements of the same priority in the queue doesn't maintain the insertion order and I can't reporoduce it in PHP!

Comment: Java's `PriorityQueue` class uses a [min-heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) to maintain the queue. You could duplicate its ordering behavior if you were to translate the Java code to PHP. Note that what you describe is pretty standard behavior for a priority queue in any language.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. I just answer my own question for reference for others.
Java documentation says

> If multiple elements are tied for least value, the head is one of those elements -- ties are broken arbitrarily.

That means if there are multiple elements with the same priority, then Java just puts them whatever order it wants. Not FIFO, not alphabetical, not anything. That's not really practical or logical to me. Anyway, that means that it is IMPOSSIBLE to exactly represent this behaviour in PHP, so I'll stick with just ordering the elements by priority, then FIFO.